# iterable unpacking results in empty object after first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator

Using the * iterable unpacking operator features I would like to maintain the content of a variable so that I can use the variable at multiple places in my code.
Here is a little example expressing what I would like:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = None
>>> c = None
>>> args = (x for x in (a, b, c) if x is not None)
>>> print(*args)
>>> 1
>>> print(*args)
>>>
```

The second print returns nothing because `args` has been unpacked during the first `print` statement.

Is there a way to maintain the content of a variable by still using the * feature? Obviously, I can delegate `(x for x in (a, b, c) if x is not None)` into a dedicated function that I will call all the time. I was wondering if there was a simpler / more pythonic way to handle the operation.

Comment: The second `print` prints nothing because the generator has been exhausted (by the unpacking indeed, but that's only a side effect - you wouldn't have the problem using a list or tuple instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `[x for x in (a, b, c) if x is not None]` *(with square brackets)* instead of `(x for x in (a, b, c) if x is not None)`.

`(...)` creates a generator which becomes empty once iterated. Whereas `[...]` is the syntax of *list comprehension* which returns the list.

For example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = None
>>> c = None
>>> args = [x for x in (a, b, c) if x is not None]
>>> print(*args)
1
>>> print(*args)
1
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer! another tip in the toolbox